# program a button to stop infinite loop

Tags: vba, excel

I want to display excel sheets in workbook 1 continuously so I use an infinite loop. 
My questions is when I need to update the data in those sheets I must stop the infinite loop, how can I do that using VBA code? For example I want to press a button in workbook 2 to stop the infinite loop in workbook 1 (BTW I cant put the button in workbook 1 because the sheets are changed continuously

or does anyone have a better idea how to display sheets continuously?

Here is the code : 
**So Sheet MacroKeys is only contains a word in cell A1 =yes  as a trigger to display each sheet for a 2 seconds (sheet1,sheet2,sheet3 then back to sheet 1 again & repeat the process infinitely

```
Sub Show_Sheet1()
Dim MacroKeys As Worksheet: Set MacroKeys = Sheets("MacroKeys")
Dim Sh1 As Worksheet: Set Sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim Sh2 As Worksheet: Set Sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Dim Sh3 As Worksheet: Set Sh3 = Sheets("Sheet3")

MacroKeys.Range("A1") = "Yes"
' [...]
Sh1.Visible = True
Sh1.Select
Sh2.Visible = False
Sh3.Visible = False

' [...]
If MacroKeys.Range("A1") = "Yes" Then
alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
Application.OnTime alertTime, "Show_Sheet2"
    End If
End Sub

Sub Show_Sheet2()
Dim MacroKeys As Worksheet: Set MacroKeys = Sheets("MacroKeys")
Dim Sh1 As Worksheet: Set Sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim Sh2 As Worksheet: Set Sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Dim Sh3 As Worksheet: Set Sh3 = Sheets("Sheet3")

    MacroKeys.Range("A1") = "Yes"
    ' [...]
    Sh2.Visible = True
    Sh2.Select
    Sh1.Visible = False
    Sh3.Visible = False

    ' [...]
    If MacroKeys.Range("A1") = "Yes" Then
    alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "Show_Sheet3"
    End If
    End Sub

Sub Show_Sheet3()
Dim MacroKeys As Worksheet: Set MacroKeys = Sheets("MacroKeys")
Dim Sh1 As Worksheet: Set Sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim Sh2 As Worksheet: Set Sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Dim Sh3 As Worksheet: Set Sh3 = Sheets("Sheet3")

MacroKeys.Range("A1") = "Yes"
' [...]
Sh3.Visible = True
Sh3.Select
Sh1.Visible = False
Sh2.Visible = False

' [...]
If MacroKeys.Range("A1") = "Yes" Then
alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
Application.OnTime alertTime, "Show_Sheet1"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please also explain what you mean by "display excel sheets...continuously"

Comment: ...Why do you have an infinite loop? How does that even run without locking up Excel/your computer?

Comment: these sheets contain data, i want to display it on a screen all the day its like the (digital signage)

Comment: instead of looping worksheets, you could display only one worksheet and copy one of the other sheets to it every time you want to change the display  .... another way is to have each of the sheets on a powerpoint slide

Comment: You could just stop the code running without VBA http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/interrupt-a-macro.html

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're using some sort of Application.OnTime() function for your "continuous loop".  Set a boolean variable "Loop" to "True" or "False", and in your method to change sheet, have a check as to whether the boolean is true or not.  Have a button that sets the boolean to false.

If you post some code that you're already using, we can help refine it.

Edit:  Some code / more definition:
You can use a Modeless Form to control the start/stop.  To do this, use the vbModeLess argument in the .Show() method:

```
Dim oForm As UserForm1
Set oForm = New UserForm1
oForm.Show vbModeless
```

The Userform can then have buttons to start and stop the looping:  To start it, set a public boolean to `True`to continue looping, and start the loop.  To stop it, have another button to set the same boolean to `false`.

Use better button names, but here is the simple code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
ContinueLoop = True
LoopingController
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
ContinueLoop = False
Unload Me
End Sub
```

In terms of the other code:  Variables to control the Looping (in a standard module):

```
Public ContinueLoop As Boolean
Public Const IntervalSeconds = 5
Public Const codeToRun = "LoopingController"
```

The code to run the loop:

```
Public Sub LoopingController()
If ContinueLoop = True Then
    LoopAction
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, IntervalSeconds), codeToRun       '//This calls itself, as long as the looping variable is 'true'
End If
End Sub
```

And the code that actually runs each time:

```
Public Function LoopAction()
Dim visibleSheetIndex As Long
visibleSheetIndex = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Index

If (visibleSheetIndex = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count) Then
    visibleSheetIndex = 1
Else
    visibleSheetIndex = visibleSheetIndex + 1
End If

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(visibleSheetIndex).Activate
End Function
```

You can kick it off via:

```
Public Sub test()

Dim oForm As UserForm1
Set oForm = New UserForm1
oForm.Show vbModeless

End Sub
```

Sorry - I'm spoon-feeding the code here, but I like a challenge.  You can also set the [start-up position](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/startupposition-property) to make it a little less obtrusive.

Also, you could do something similar with a ToggleButton on the Ribbon.